# Unable to handle background process for data store in database and document directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

I am selecting multiple image and video from photos gallery and store assets path into database and original assets into application document directory. For this process, until it is complete i showing progress bar with status.
But the problem is when i start saving process progress bar status remain same and it will increase process status after save operation completed.
I am using SVProgressHUD for show progress bar.
Code i did after picking assets.

```
static float progress = 0.0f;
progress = 0.0f;
[SVProgressHUD showProgress:0 status:@"Loading"];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(SaveAssetToSQL) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(load_Album_Data) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

i call IncreaseProgress method at time of data are saved one by one.
Method for save assets.

```
-(void)SaveAssetToSQL{

for (int i=0; i<TotalAssets; i++) {
   [self performSelector:@selector(increaseProgress) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3f];
   //further process for save
  }
}
```

Method for IncreaseProcess

```
 - (void)increaseProgress {
      progress+=0.1f;
      [SVProgressHUD showProgress:progress status:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",progress]];

    if(progress < 1.0f)
        [self performSelector:@selector(increaseProgress) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.9f];
    else
        [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4f];
    }
```

I have to show progress bar and it status till assets storage process complete. Also i tried to put that storage process in background thread using GCD but unable to show progress status.
Please help me to solve this.
Please suggest me a way to handle this process.
As related to my problem there is any way to handle storage process in background and show progress bar status in foreground.
Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take the following approach using `GCD` for the long-running operation.

- Perform the file saving part in a different thread.
- Calculate the percent completed after each file copy.
- Call the progress update on the main thread.

It should look something similar to the below code. I'm just hosting the skeleton code for you.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

    __block percentCompleted = 0;

    NSArray *files = [self getFiles];//assume you get the file locations from this method.

    for(NSString *filepath in files){//loop the files

        //Perform copying file to new location
        //Calculate how much percent has been completed
        percentCompleted = <newValue>;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update progress-bar UI

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: can u suggest me where i have to call load_Album_Data, i write it below the  above process but it execute before saving process over

Comment: Can you try my solution and show me your code if it doesn't work. I'm travelling now and have limited access.

Comment: Yes, its completely working for me.And also solved my problem i wrote in comment.